# I want to remove windows partition using gparted

Tags: gparted

I want to remove my windows partition using Gparted. What should I do besides Backing up my data before I commence this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not much ... backup **ALL IMPORTANT data**, make sure that you are deleting the **right** partition. Proceed with deletion of the Windows partition - afterwards update GRUB : `sudo update-grub`

Refer here for more details : **https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToRemoveWindows**

Answer (score 1):

1. All important data
2. Check Firefox and Chrome bookmarks, WMP play lists. Also any scripts you might have created...
3. Go to Users/USERNAME and check all folders in it. Eg. Documents,  pictures,  downloads, etc.
4. Also check for any projects (Netbeans, VS) you may have created and saved in the Windows drive.