# Removing dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

At the beginning of the year, I ran a Windows Ubuntu dual boot on my PC
I recently decided that I just want Ubuntu as the sole OS.
Having deleted the Windows partitions and entry on GRUB, the part that's left is reclaiming the unallocated space claimed by Windows earlier. Please how do I go about this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to remove windows partition using gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774552/i-want-to-remove-windows-partition-using-gparted)

Comment: Is there a more GUI inclined way

Comment: You've not provided any details as to what Ubuntu product/release you're talking about; but assuming your Ubuntu system controls the boot process, you can just whatever graphical partitioning tool (such as `gparted`, *KDE Partition Manager* or whatever your *unstated* system has installed) to remove the unwanted partition. We can't know what you're running unless you specifically tell us.

Comment: To reclaim the space you have released you need to move and resize your remaining partition(s). The process to do this is described in this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: If you do not want to move partitions which has a higher risk as any interruption can totally damage data, you can move /home or use an ext4 partition for data from /home. Make sure you have good backups, first. [Move Home](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk